# VB.Net Search multiple context of the Bible

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

Dear All dotnet Developers,

I am asking your favor for I am a newbie in vb.net. Im trying to develop a small program that could help in our local church for displying the verses in the bible to be used in our sunday school. I used only bible.txt file as my source, the format of the context inside bible.txt is look like these:

Genesis 1:1 In the beginning God created the heavens and the earth.

Genesis 1:2 and darkness was over the surface of the deep, and the Spirit of God was hovering over the waters.

Genesis 1:3 And God said, “Let there be light,” and there was light.

Genesis 1:4 God saw that the light was good, and he separated the light from the darkness.

Genesis 1:5 God called the light “day,” and the darkness he called “night.” And there was evening, and there was morning—the first day.

Genesis 1:6 And God said, “Let there be a vault between the waters to separate water from water.”

Now, how can i search multiple verses? example if I want to search like these:

there are three textbox, one for the book (ie. Genesis) one for the chapter (ie. 1) and one for the verse (ie. 1-2,4-6)

: Genesis 1: 1-2,4-6

or if it is not possible all i can do is only searching one by one, 1 verse at a time.  Is it possible that in the richtextbox, it add the search verse?

example I search first: Genesis 1:1, next Genesis 1:2, next again Genesis 1:4

The result in the richtextbox:

Genesis 1:1 In the beginning God created the heavens and the earth.

Genesis 1:2 and darkness was over the surface of the deep, and the Spirit of God was hovering over the waters.

Genesis 1:4 God saw that the light was good, and he separated the light from the darkness.

Thanks if anyone can help me.

Comment: Since it's just a .txt file you would need to somehow preprocess the text and build an index, or scan the text line by line looking for your search markers.

Comment: Is that the exact format of the text? bookname with at least one space after it then chapter with a colon separating it from the verse, and then at least one space separating it from the verse text? Also is each verse all on one line?

Comment: OK I'm working on it - I'll be writing it tomorrow - damn - later today

Comment: In the mean time, try adding some code to show what work you've done so far - It might stop the question being closed as to broad ;)

Comment: @Trehv - this is getting rather large - how do you feel about emailing me? My address is in my profile

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```css
Public Class Form1
    Dim verses As List(Of Verse) = New List(Of Verse)({ _
       New Verse() With {.book = "Genesis", .chapter = 1, .paragraph = 1, .text = "In the beginning God created the heavens and the earth."},
       New Verse() With {.book = "Genesis", .chapter = 1, .paragraph = 2, .text = "and darkness was over the surface of the deep, and the Spirit of God was hovering over the waters."},
       New Verse() With {.book = "Genesis", .chapter = 1, .paragraph = 3, .text = "And God said, ""Let there be light,"" and there was light."},
       New Verse() With {.book = "Genesis", .chapter = 1, .paragraph = 4, .text = "God saw that the light was good, and he separated the light from the darkness."},
       New Verse() With {.book = "Genesis", .chapter = 1, .paragraph = 5, .text = "God called the light ""day,"" and the darkness he called ""night."" And there was evening, and there was morning—the first day."},
       New Verse() With {.book = "Genesis", .chapter = 1, .paragraph = 6, .text = "Let there be a vault between the waters to separate water from water."}
   })

 

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim results As List(Of Verse) = verses.Where(Function(x) x.book = "Genesis").ToList

        Dim light As List(Of Verse) = verses.Where(Function(x) x.text.ToUpper().Contains("LIGHT")).ToList
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Verse
    Private nBook As String
    Public Property book As String
        Get
            Return nBook
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            nBook = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private nChapter As Integer
    Public Property chapter As Integer
        Get
            Return nChapter
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            nChapter = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private nParagraph As String
    Public Property paragraph As Integer
        Get
            Return nParagraph
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            nParagraph = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private nText As String
    Public Property text As String
        Get
            Return nText
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            nText = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
​
```

Answer (score 0):

Hokay, This is a pretty big answer. This code reads the bible text file and parses it into a datatable with columns for the book names, chapters,verses and verse text There is also code to save the datatable and read it back if it exists.

This should point you in the right direction.

If you need help for searching the datatable, email me , as the code for parsing the searches and displaying it needs controls on forms etc, and to be honest, it would be easier to send you a zip of the entire solution - which I suspect is not appropriate within the forum.

I wrote this code using visual studio community 2015 edition which you can download for free from Microsoft. It might work on your 2010 version, but I cant be sure.

You will need to drag and drop the bible.txt file to your project and when you've done that, you need to click on the file in your project and click copy if newer on the Copy to Output Directory

```
    Dim biblePath As String = Application.StartupPath() & "\bible.txt"
    Dim bibleXmlPath As String = Application.StartupPath() & "\bible.xml"
    Dim appPath As String = Application.StartupPath

    Structure bibleVerse
        Dim Book As String
        Dim Chapter As Integer
        Dim VerseNumber As Integer
        Dim VerseText As String
    End Structure

    Dim bible As New DataTable

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        InitializeBibleTable()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Shown
        If File.Exists(bibleXmlPath) Then
            loadBible(bibleXmlPath, bible)
        Else
            readBibleFromTextFile()
            saveBible(bibleXmlPath, bible)
        End If
        initializeDropDownList()
    End Sub

    Public Sub InitializeBibleTable()
        Dim Book As DataColumn
        Dim Chapter As DataColumn
        Dim VerseNumber As DataColumn
        Dim VerseText As DataColumn
        bible = New DataTable("Bible")
        With bible
            Book = New DataColumn("Book")
            Chapter = New DataColumn("Chapter")
            VerseNumber = New DataColumn("VerseNumber")
            VerseText = New DataColumn("VerseText")
            Book.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String")
            Chapter.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Int16")
            VerseNumber.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Int16")
            VerseText.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String")
            .Columns.Add(Book)
            .Columns.Add(Chapter)
            .Columns.Add(VerseNumber)
            .Columns.Add(VerseText)
        End With
    End Sub

     Public Sub loadBible(filename As String, tbl As DataTable)
        Dim tableFile As System.IO.StreamReader
        tableFile = New System.IO.StreamReader(filename)
        tbl.ReadXml(tableFile)
        tableFile.Close()
    End Sub

    Public Sub saveBible(filename As String, tbl As DataTable)
        Dim tableFile As System.IO.StreamWriter
        tableFile = New System.IO.StreamWriter(filename)
        tbl.WriteXml(tableFile, XmlWriteMode.IgnoreSchema)
        tableFile.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub readBibleFromTextFile()
        Dim fileReader As System.IO.StreamReader
        fileReader = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileReader(biblePath)
        Dim stringReader As String
        While Not fileReader.EndOfStream
            stringReader = fileReader.ReadLine()
            If Not (stringReader = "") Then
                Dim biblerow As DataRow = bible.NewRow
                Dim tempverse As bibleVerse
                tempverse = parseVerse(stringReader)
                biblerow(0) = tempverse.Book
                biblerow(1) = tempverse.Chapter
                biblerow(2) = tempverse.VerseNumber
                biblerow(3) = tempverse.VerseText
                bible.Rows.Add(biblerow)
            End If
        End While
    End Sub

    Function CheckForOKCharacters(ByVal charToCheck As String, validationString As String) As Boolean
        If validationString.Contains(charToCheck) Then
            Return True
        End If
        Return False
    End Function

    Private Function parseVerse(tempVerse As String) As bibleVerse
        Dim parsedVerse As New bibleVerse
        Dim OKCharacters As String = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ .,;:!?"
        Dim OKNumbers As String = "1234567890"
        Dim book, verseText As String
        Dim chapter, verseNum As String
        Dim Parsepoint As Integer
        'start parsing book name
        book = ""
        chapter = ""
        verseNum = ""
        verseText = ""
        Parsepoint = 0
        'parse book name
        If IsNumeric(tempVerse(0)) Then
            book = book & tempVerse(0) & " "
            Parsepoint += 2
        End If
        Dim charIsOk As Boolean
        Dim checkChar As String
        Do
            checkChar = tempVerse(Parsepoint)
            charIsOk = CheckForOKCharacters(checkChar, OKCharacters)
            If charIsOk Then
                book = book & checkChar
            End If
            Parsepoint += 1
        Loop Until charIsOk = False
        book = book.Trim()
        'search for chapter number
        Parsepoint -= 1
        Do
            checkChar = tempVerse(Parsepoint)
            charIsOk = CheckForOKCharacters(checkChar, OKNumbers)
            If Not charIsOk Then
                Parsepoint += 1
            End If
        Loop Until charIsOk = True
        'parse chapternumber
        Do
            checkChar = tempVerse(Parsepoint)
            charIsOk = CheckForOKCharacters(checkChar, OKNumbers)
            If charIsOk Then
                chapter = chapter & checkChar
            End If
            Parsepoint += 1
        Loop Until charIsOk = False
        'parse verse number
        Do
            checkChar = tempVerse(Parsepoint)
            charIsOk = CheckForOKCharacters(checkChar, OKNumbers)
            If charIsOk Then
                verseNum = verseNum & checkChar
            End If
            Parsepoint += 1
        Loop Until charIsOk = False
        'search for verse text
        Parsepoint -= 1
        Do
            checkChar = tempVerse(Parsepoint)
            charIsOk = CheckForOKCharacters(checkChar, OKCharacters)
            If Not charIsOk Then
                Parsepoint += 1
            End If
        Loop Until charIsOk = True
        'get verse text from remainder of string
        verseText = tempVerse.Substring(Parsepoint)
        'put parsed values into parsedverse structure and return it
        parsedVerse.Book = book
        parsedVerse.Chapter = CInt(chapter)
        parsedVerse.VerseNumber = CInt(verseNum)
        parsedVerse.VerseText = verseText
        Return parsedVerse
    End Function
```